# VBA delete list of folders in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dir

I am using an application called "All Dup" to find duplicate files, normally matching by CRC checksum. Once I have run the scan I am left with a list of about 10000 duplicate files. I can then export the results as a csv file. What I would like to do is have a Macro that will go and delete all the specified folders in a column, i.e, I have all the folders in column A.

I know how to delete a single directory, but would really appreciate some help with a "loop" function or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will walk down column A from row 2 to the last populated row. Each cell is first examined to see if it is non-blank then it is examined to see if it exists as a folder with the [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx).

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For dr = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If CBool(Len(.Cells(dr, "A").Value2)) Then
            If CBool(Len(Dir(.Cells(dr, "A").Value2, vbdirectrory))) Then
                Kill .Cells(dr, "A").Value2 & Chr(92) * Chr(42)
                RmDir .Cells(dr, "A").Value2 
            End If
        End If
    Next dr
End With
```

If both tests pass, then the folder is removed with the [Kill function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1w10ch.aspx). If the folder is populated with files, they should be removed first.

Comment: Great, thank you. What command will remove the directory regardless of whether it has files or not?

Comment: first, **Kill directory & "\*.\*"** 'delete all files in the folder C:\directory\\*.*

Comment: then **RmDir** directory 'delete folder C:\directory\

Comment: Thank you @daniel; I had taken the OP at his/her word that *'I know how to delete a single directory'*.

Comment: @Jeeped After some trial and error I realized that my csv was not importing the "\" at the end of the directory. The code is working, but how do you delete all sub directories and contents as well? I have tried variations but with no luck. 'code' |Sub deletedir()

On Error Resume Next
With Worksheets("Folders")
    For Dr = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If CBool(Len(.Cells(Dr, "A").Value2)) Then
                Kill .Cells(Dr, "A").Value2 & "*.*"
                RmDir .Cells(Dr, "A").Value2 & "\"
            End If
    Next Dr
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub